# Cant find class?

Tags: java, android, xml, string, algorithm

For some reason, I am unable to find the class from my intent, and I get this error:

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.ruchirb.tutorial/com.example.ruchirb.tutorial.myIntro}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

It happens when I try to start my activity:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, myIntro.class);
                    startActivity(i);
```

And I **have** declared it in my manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <activity //RIGHT HERE !!!!!!! SEE ITS DECLARED!!!
            android:name=".myIntro" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"

            />

    </activity>
</application>
```

I don't have a layout for the class, because I am trying to make an introduction tutorial using this library:

https://github.com/PaoloRotolo/AppIntro

Here is the code for my `myIntro.class`:

```
package com.example.ruchirb.tutorial;


import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.ruchirb.tutorial.R;
import com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntro;
import com.github.paolorotolo.appintro.AppIntroFragment;

public class myIntro extends AppIntro {

    // Please DO NOT override onCreate. Use init.
    @Override
    public void init(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Add your slide's fragments here.
        // AppIntro will automatically generate the dots indicator and buttons.
        addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("Hello", "Sup bro", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, Color.RED));
        addSlide(AppIntroFragment.newInstance("NUMBER 2", "Hello again", R.mipmap.ic_launcher, Color.BLUE));




        // OPTIONAL METHODS
        // Override bar/separator color.
        setBarColor(Color.parseColor("#3F51B5"));
        setSeparatorColor(Color.parseColor("#2196F3"));

        // Hide Skip/Done button.
        showSkipButton(false);
        setProgressButtonEnabled(false);

        // Turn vibration on and set intensity.
        // NOTE: you will probably need to ask VIBRATE permisssion in Manifest.
        setVibrate(true);
        setVibrateIntensity(30);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSkipPressed() {
        // Do something when users tap on Skip button.
    }

    @Override
    public void onDonePressed() {
        // Do something when users tap on Done button.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSlideChanged() {
        // Do something when the slide changes.
    }

    @Override
    public void onNextPressed() {
        // Do something when users tap on Next button.
    }

}
```

What could the problem be?

Thanks,

Ruchir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have error in the syntax. Second activity was declared within first activity. All activities must be declared under `application` only.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity <!-- should be inside application not inside above activity -->
        android:name=".myIntro" 
        android:label="@string/app_name"

 />
```

Should be like above.